# FCM not receiving notification messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have my manifest in check, my services in check, my dependencies in check, class variables in check and still no notifications on my device. I'm using my computer to send firebase cloud messages and I should be receiving them on my android phone. However,my android phone is not picking up the notifications. And yes, my android device is in the background as I send the message. Anyone know what my problem is?

Here's the source code:

**My Service**

```
public class FirebaseIDMessage extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDMessage";


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        String token = s;
        Log.d(TAG, "Registered token: = " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token){

    }
}
```

**My Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.messaging">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

       <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Services -->
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDMessage"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MessagingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Activity**

```
public class MessagingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messaging);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file, you are missing INSTANCE_ID_EVENT

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

This is the intent-filter for the Class extended with FirebaseInstanceIdService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
   public static final String REGISTRATION_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";
   @Override
     public void onTokenRefresh()
     {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e(REGISTRATION_TOKEN,token);
     }
 }
```

So, finally the manifest service will be like

```
   <service android:name=".Utils.PushNotification.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the log you would have got registered Token. Your all set only if you receive that token.

Goto Firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com

Choose your project -> From the left side menu -> Choose Cloud Messaging -> New Message

Type your message and then in the TARGET choose Single Device and then copy paste your received token and check on your device for this notification by this way we can confirm you have set all notification related code correctly. If you still face any problem please let know so that I can share some samples.